# Modular Arithmetic Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I prove that if $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0≡0 \pmod p$ has more than $n$ solutions, then all $a_i≡0 \pmod p$? Is it possible to solve this using contra positivity, if not what other alternative method is there to approach the problem? I am kind of confused with how to solve it.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: Is $p$ a prime? Otherwise the statement is false: take $p=6$ and $3x^2-3x$ is always divisible by $6$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop . Or if $p=12$ then $x^2-7x\equiv x^2-7x+12\equiv (x-3)(x-4)\equiv  0\pmod {12}$  has 3 solutions $0,3,4$ mod $12$.

Comment: If $p$ is prime then arithmetic on $\Bbb Z_{/p}$ is a $field$.

Comment: Iterate the *Factor Theorem* as in the linked dupes.